# FCM strange error: only "to" in the response body

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm doing performance testing on our FCM notification server with fake device tokens and should be getting an error like the following:

```
{
     "multicast_id":6782339717028231855,
     "success":0,
     "failure":1,
     "canonical_ids":0,
     "results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}
      ]
}
```

But about 3-5 requests out of 600K requests, we see a 400 error with a response body like this:

`to`

We know the json is formed correctly since we log the json body if we get any sort of error.

Has anyone seen any strange error/response body similar to this?

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Did you find out what it was?

Answer (score 0):

Error `400` means `Invalid Json request` and the response body with only `to` means the problem is an invalid `registration_ids` or `to` field.

In my case I was emitting a Downstream message to every user, including the ones that haven't yet registered with `FCM`, so some of those had an empty recipient value.